# How in scss select children by condition?

Tags: html, css, sass, odoo, scss-mixins

i have next html code. Framework(Odoo-15, widget="priority") generates it by himself, so i cant do any changes here.

```
<div role="radiogroup" class="o_priority o_field_widget" name="priority" aria-label="Пріоритет">
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Низький" aria-label="Низький" tabindex="-1" data-index="1" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Звичайний" aria-label="Звичайний" tabindex="-1" data-index="2" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Високий" aria-label="Високий" tabindex="-1" data-index="3" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="true" title="Критичний" aria-label="Критичний" tabindex="0" data-index="4" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star-o" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Невідкладний" aria-label="Невідкладний" tabindex="-1" data-index="5" ></a>
</div>
```

i can use scss and i want to do next:

if `<div>` have child `<a>` with attributes `[aria-checked="true"][data-index="4"]` , then apply style: `color: red` to all his childs `<a>` with `class="o_priority_star fa fa-star"`

how to do that?

Comment: The short answer: this is not (yet) possible.
The longer answer: when browsers start supporting `:has()` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)) you can use it to check the condition.

Comment: You can extend the [priority](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L2459) widget and redefine the [_render](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/abstract_field.js#L499) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement can be done like so, default set the color to red for all, then select the currently selected star and set the color to inherit or whatever you want, also select the adjacent ones using the css selector `~` and inherit the color the same way. Please check the below example!

```css
div > a[aria-checked="true"] {
color: inherit !important;
}  

div > a[aria-checked="true"] ~ a.o_priority_star.fa.fa-star-o {
color: inherit !important;
}

div > a[aria-checked="true"] ~ a.o_priority_star.fa.fa-star {
color: inherit !important;
}


a.o_priority_star.fa.fa-star {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div role="radiogroup" class="o_priority o_field_widget" name="priority" aria-label="Пріоритет">
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Низький" aria-label="Низький" tabindex="-1" data-index="1" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Звичайний" aria-label="Звичайний" tabindex="-1" data-index="2" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Високий" aria-label="Високий" tabindex="-1" data-index="3" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="true" title="Критичний" aria-label="Критичний" tabindex="0" data-index="4" ></a>
    <a class="o_priority_star fa fa-star-o" href="#" role="radio" aria-checked="false" title="Невідкладний" aria-label="Невідкладний" tabindex="-1" data-index="5" ></a>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```